# MockMVC and Mockito returns Status expected <200> but was <415>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito

I'm testing an api endpoint which works from a http poster (namely PAW) but I cant get a test in the code to pass.

I'm new to both Mockito and MockMVC so any help would be appreciated.

Test below:

```
 @Test
 public void createPaymentTest() throws Exception {
    User user = new User("ben", "password", "a@a.com");

    SuccessResponseDTO successDTO = new SuccessResponseDTO();
    successDTO.setSuccess(true);

    when(userService.getLoggedInUser()).thenReturn(user);
    when(paymentService.makePayment(Mockito.any(PaymentRequestDTO.class), Mockito.any(User.class))).thenReturn(successDTO.getSuccess());

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/payment")).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.success").value(successDTO.getSuccess()));

}
```

SuccessResponseDTO just contains one attribute, a boolean 'success'.

The method it's testing is below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public SuccessResponseDTO createPayment(@RequestBody PaymentRequestDTO payment) {
    User loggedInUser = userService.getLoggedInUser();
    LOGGER.info("Logged in user found...creating payment...");

    Assert.notNull(payment.getAccountId(), "Missing user account id");
    Assert.notNull(payment.getPayeeAccountNumber(), "Missing payee acount number");
    Assert.notNull(payment.getPayeeName(), "Missing payee name");
    Assert.notNull(payment.getPayeeSortCode(), "Missing payee sort code");
    Assert.notNull(payment.getPaymentAmount(), "Missing payee amount");
    Assert.notNull(payment.getPaymentDescription(), "Missing payment description");

    Boolean paymentResult = paymentService.makePayment(payment, loggedInUser);

    SuccessResponseDTO successResponse = new SuccessResponseDTO();

    successResponse.setSuccess(paymentResult);

    return successResponse;
}
```

Can anyone shed light on the stack trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<415>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:546)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
at com.capco.living.controller.PaymentControllerTest.createPaymentTest(PaymentControllerTest.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[HTTP Error 415 Unsupported media type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - means that you send the data which is not supported by the service. In this case it means that you don't set the Content-Type header and actual content in the request. I suppose the JSON  is expected content, so your call should look like this:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(post("/payment").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content("{\"json\":\"request to be send\"}"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .and_the_rest_of_validation_part
```

Answer (score 11):

You might also be missing some annotations on your controller class. Make sure you use @EnableWebMvc and @Controller

Check out [this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25573651/1860768)

Answer (score 1):

Also you might add accept

```
 mockMvc.perform(post("/api/sender/sms/")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content("{ \"serviceName\":\"serviceName\",  \"apiId\":\"apiId\",  \"to\":\"to\",  \"msg\":\"msg\" }")
    )
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
```